# Ruby Time.strptime vs Date.strptime

Tags: ruby

When parsing "some dates" (in Ruby) with `Time.strptime` and `Date.strptime` have different behaviour.

For example if we try to convert "30 Feb" (a date that does not exist), we have:

```
Time.strptime('30 Feb 2015', '%d %b %Y') # will result in this date: 2015-03-02
Date.strptime('30 Feb 2015', '%d %b %Y') # ArgumentError: invalid date
```

At the same time trying to parse "32 Feb" results in error for both classes.

```
Time.strptime('32 Feb 2015', '%d %b %Y') # ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - `%d %b %Y'
Date.strptime('32 Feb 2015', '%d %b %Y') # ArgumentError: invalid date
```

What is the reason for the different behaviour? Why Time "attempts to adjust" an invalid date?

Comment: Bug in implementation, I assume? Have you looked at them?

Comment: Well it might be, but it seems they are doing something on purpose: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/time.rb#L426. Since for `Time.strptime` they are using `Date._strptime`, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did a bit more digging and found a couple of "issues" reported on this topic: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9549 and the main one: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10588

It seams that `Time` behaves this way for a reason. As Akira Tanaka says:

> Invalid date/time is difficult to determine.
>   It is almost impossible by application because it depends various factors:
>   Month, leap year, summer time, leap seconds, time zone definition change.
>
> Sometimes application needs a Time object near given year/month/day/hour/minute/second.

So `Time` tries to compensate possible 'almost correct' times. That's why it successfully parses this:
`Time.strptime('29 Mar 2015 3:30:00 +02000', '%d %b %Y %T %z')` to 
2015-03-29 04:30:00 +0300 (3:30 is invalid time on 29th March 2015 because of daylight saving time, from 3:00 the clock moves to 4:00)